# Silencing warnings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

When running:

```
mydf = pd.read_csv(p_file, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False)
```

I get many lines like the following:

> ```
> ...
> Skipping line 77432: expected 15 fields, saw 16
> Skipping line 77497: expected 15 fields, saw 16
> Skipping line 77528: expected 15 fields, saw 16
> Skipping line 77560: expected 15 fields, saw 16
> Skipping line 77625: expected 15 fields, saw 16
> Skipping line 77656: expected 15 fields, saw 16
> ...
> ```

How can I silence these warnings? How can I find the list of warning classes in Pandas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function read_csv has the kwarg `on_bad_lines`, so you should be able to do the following:

```
mydf = pd.read_csv(p_file, sep=',', index_col=False, on_bad_lines = 'skip')
```

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)

> on_bad_lines{‘error’, ‘warn’, ‘skip’} or callable, default ‘error’. Specifies what to do upon encountering a bad line (a line with too many fields).